# Remove layers from a custom pre-trained model

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I did transfer learning on the Inception model from keras like this:

```
base_model = applications.InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=input_shape)

model_top = Sequential()
model_top.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D(input_shape=base_model.output_shape[1:], data_format=None))
model_top.add(Dropout(0.4))
model_top.add(Dense(2))
model_top.add(Activation("softmax"))

# model_top.summary()

model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=model_top(base_model.output))
```

I want to extract features from the GlobalAveragePooling layer using the trained model, but I don't know how to access it. 
After loading the model the summary look like this:[image]

If a show the summary for `self.model.layers[-1]` I can see the GlobalAveragePooling, Dropout and the Dense layer that are in the Sequential, but not the Inception layers. What I want is the Inception layers, followed by just GlobalAveragePooling.

Is this possible or I have to make the architecture again using the functional API and retrain the whole thing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Adding the Inception model directly in the Sequential is working for me:

```py
from keras import applications
from keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dropout, Dense, Activation
from keras.models import Model, Sequential

input_shape = (299, 299, 3)

base_model = applications.InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=input_shape)

model = Sequential([
    applications.InceptionV3(weights='imagenet', include_top=False),
    GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
    Dropout(0.4),
    Dense(2),
    Activation("softmax")
])
model.summary()

submodel = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=model.get_layer("global_average_pooling2d_1").output)
submodel.summary()
```

Comment: Yes, but this means that I need to train again. I have .hdf5 file with the weights and the architecture I've described before, and from this architecture I want to remove the last 2 layers to get to GlobalAveragePooling. I want to use the checkpoints that I have to make feature extraction. I hope I made it clearer now. Thank you!